# How can I use this Fastfile ?, run_tests give me zsh: command not found: run_tests

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, terminal, fastlane

I try to understand my friend project contains fastlane file and I try to figure out , what that means and how can i work with this files in terminal ?

There are 3 files Appfile, Fastfile also Matchfile

*Fastfile*

```
default_platform(:ios)


platform :ios do

  before_all do
    
  end

  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :custom_lane do
    # add actions here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
  end

end
```

*Appfile*

```
app_identifier("com.alex.PokemonFinder") # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id("qwer810520@gmail.com") # Your Apple email address

# You can uncomment any of the lines below and add your own
# team selection in case you're in multiple teams
team_name("Alex Adam")
team_id("ZLWY9M752A")
```

*Mathcfile*

```
    git_url("https://#{ENV['GITHUB_SUBMODULES_USER']}@github.com/alex/certificates.git")
    
    #git_url("git@github.com:alex/certificates.git")
    
    storage_mode("git")
    
    type("development") # The default type, can be: appstore, adhoc, enterprise or development

app_identifier([
  "com.alex.PokemonFinder",
  "com.alex.PokemonFinder"
  ])
username("qwer810520@gmail.com") # Your Apple Developer Portal username
```

I tried to run_tests in my terminal but give me `zsh: command not found: run_tests`. How can I use this files ?

Comment: I believe these files (and therefore your question) make no sense outside of fastlane context. So, the best place to look for answers is fastlane documentation. For example, take a look at https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/running-tests/

Comment: You have wrong belief. I believe an experienced developer will come and explain a little bit for me. I already read the documentation that is why i run the`run_tests` so IMO best place to look answers is stackoverflow.

Comment: `I tried to run_tests in my terminal`, your Fastfile doesn't contain a `run_tests` lane, at least not the fastfile you added to the question.